# Override arguments of parent symfony service using defaults

Tags: php, symfony

world!

I'm trying to override some arguments of basic PHP-class in Symfony DI, using parent attribute, but I can't.

Basic class has many arguments and their defaults are described in abstract symfony service. The YAML:

```
    App\BasicClass:
      class: App\BasicClass
      public: false
      abstract: true
      arguments:
        - '@App\Finder\DefaultFinder' #App\Finder\FinderInterface
        - '@App\Builder\DefaultBuilder' #App\Builder\BuilderInterface
        - ...
        - ...
        - !php/const App\Enum\CountryCode::COUNTRY_UNDEFINED
```

In my child class I need to override just 3 of them. What I've tried:

```
    app.myChildClass:
      parent: App\BasicClass
      bind:
        App\Finder\FinderInterface: '@App\Finder\CustomFinder'
        App\Builder\BuilderInterface: '@App\Finder\CustomBuilder'
```

In this case I get an error:

> A binding is configured for an argument of type \"App\\Finder\\FinderInterface\" for service \"app.myChildClass\", but no corresponding argument has been found

Even though namespace of interface is correct. The same error if I specify argument name (as it is in constructor) instead of namespace:
`$finder: @App\Finder\CustomFinder`

Overriding works only if I use "arguments" attribute instead of "bind" with argument names like below:

```
app.myChildClass:
  parent: App\BasicClass
  arguments:
    $finder: '@App\Finder\CustomFinder'
    $builder: '@App\Finder\CustomBuilder'
```

But the second problem I've got is that I hoped to bind one argument (a const) through the _defaults section:

```
    _defaults:
      bind:
        $country: !php/const App\Enum\CountryCode::COUNTRY_UKR

    app.myChildClass:
      parent: App\BasicClass
      arguments:
        $finder: '@App\Finder\CustomFinder'
        $builder: '@App\Finder\CustomBuilder'
```

But id doesn't jump into my service probably due to using "arguments", not "bind" :( So I'm confused, is here any chance to simplify this overriding or I must duplicate the row

```
$country: !php/const App\Enum\CountryCode::COUNTRY_UKR
```

in my child service definition?

Thank you!

Comment: bind works with argument names which is why your attempt to bind by interfaces did not work.  It seems binding country should work assuming you have a constructor argument called $country.  Seems like you are missing the class parameter in your child definition.  Do you have autowire enabled?  This could be a case where you are not showing enough in your question.  Maybe show the complete _defaults section and the two service definitions.  Verify that this is all using one services.yaml file.